# How do I clear an AE lock on my Canon XTI?

Tags: canon, canon-400d

If I press the AE Lock (*) button on my Canon XTI it will lock the exposure, but how do I un-lock it? I usually just end up turning the camera off and then back on. After playing with my camera a minute ago I found that if I wait 4 seconds the display inside the viewfinder turns off and when I wake it back up by half pressing the shutter button the AE lock indicator is off. So do I just have to wait? I know 4 seconds is not that long but it could also mean getting or missing the shot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Canon article [Using Auto Exposure (AE) Lock](http://www.usa.canon.com/dlc/controller?act=GetArticleAct&articleID=2547) :

> ## Clearing a locked exposure:
>
> Once you’ve pressed the AE Lock button, the
> camera holds the meter reading in
> place. If you change your mind and
> want to totally eliminate AE Lock,
> don’t press the AE Lock button again.
> That simply takes a new meter reading
> and locks it in.
>
> When AE Lock is in use, an asterisk
> will be visible in the camera's
> viewfinder. Instead, either pull your
> finger off the shutter button and wait
> 4 to 6 seconds, and wait for the
> finder display to go blank. Then,
> press the shutter button back down
> again. If you’re in a hurry and don’t
> want to wait a few seconds for the
> reading to clear, **press the AF point
> select button (right next to the AE
> Lock button, on the back of the
> camera), and then immediately let it
> go and press the shutter button
> again**. You’re back to live metering
> that’s not locked in place.

Comment: Yes, pushing the AF point selection button is quite quick and simple! I used from the beginning and I'm glad that this is the correct way to do it, I thought was a trick;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you wait for the meter operating time to go off.... or you simply take a picture.

It would be preferable if it turned off with another press, but it does not.

I am not sure, but I believe changing the exposure mode (from A to P for example) also cancels it. You can try that too and it should be quick enough to just turn the mode dial and back when you want to cancel AE-L.

Comment: @Eric Or hit the AE lock button again just before taking the picture: that will reset the exposure for the picture and taking the picture cancels the lock.